# What's the difference between AddHeader and AddGlobalHeader?

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

When should I use one or the other?

[AddHeader](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/d7b22eefa4d58b25f94441b0be3f5033f6075a59/src/SendGrid/Helpers/Mail/SendGridMessage.cs#L549)
vs
[AddGlobalHeader](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/d7b22eefa4d58b25f94441b0be3f5033f6075a59/src/SendGrid/Helpers/Mail/SendGridMessage.cs#L1185)

I've looked in the code and [examples](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/cf8d7622843b76d16e3f3b2f8d32722616307807/USE_CASES.md), but I can't figure out the difference.

In my particular case, I would like to set the `Sender` header; I'm not sure which one would be appropriate or better.